# Error assigning gorm.DB to a model variable

Tags: go, grails-orm

I Need help with pointers in Golang `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`, I'm trying to return an instance of gorm `*gorm.DB` to my model in another folder

My idea is to have one variable with the connection in my model instantiated once but when I instanced in `func Init()`  I have an error

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "gitlab.com/project/database"
    "gitlab.com/project/models"
)

func main() {
    
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        panic("Error loading .env file")
    }

    database.InitDatabase()

    memes, err := models.GetAll();

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("err database get memes")
    }

    for _, meme := range memes {
        log.Printf(meme.Url)
    }
}
```

**database / database.go**

```golang
package database

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
)

var (
    DB * gorm.DB
) 

func InitDatabase(){
    d, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL")), &gorm.Config{})
    
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    DB = d
}

func GetDB() (*gorm.DB) {
    return DB
}
```

**models / meme.go**

```golang
package models

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gitlab.com/webeoparty/api/database"
)

type Meme struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id  uint32
    Source string
    Filename_local string
    Original_filename string
    Public_id string
    Url string
    Secure_url string
    Resource_type string
    Width uint32
    Height uint32
}

var Conn *gorm.DB

func init() {
    Conn = database.GetDB()
}

func GetAll() ([]Meme, error) {
    var memes []Meme

    tx := Conn.Find(&memes)

    if tx.Error != nil {
        return []Meme{}, tx.Error
    }

    return memes, nil
}
```

the error is *panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference* when i try to get the instance of `*gorm.DB` is

```bash
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x28 pc=0xf02a78]

goroutine 1 [running]:
gorm.io/gorm.(*DB).getInstance(0x280bb540108?)
        C:/Users/edoco/Documents/go-workspace/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.23.5/gorm.go:363 +0x18
gorm.io/gorm.(*DB).Find(0x12d96c8?, {0x1194c40?, 0xc000005998}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        C:/Users/edoco/Documents/go-workspace/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.23.5/finisher_api.go:163 +0x45
gitlab.com/webeoparty/api/models.GetAll()
        C:/Users/edoco/Documents/go-workspace/src/webeoparty-api/models/meme.go:34 +0x54
main.main()
        C:/Users/edoco/Documents/go-workspace/src/webeoparty-api/main.go:22 +0x4a
exit status 2
```

but When I write the method `database.GetDB()` inside of the func `GetAll()` the project run perfectly

```golang
package models

...

var Conn *gorm.DB

func GetAll() ([]Meme, error) {
    var memes []Meme

    Conn = database.GetDB()
    tx := Conn.Find(&memes)
    
    
    if tx.Error != nil {
        return []Meme{}, tx.Error
    }

    return memes, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`init()` in `models/meme.go` gets called before `DB` is assigned in `database/database.go` (`InitDatabase()` was not called yet).

This is because `init()` is special function and gets called when package is imported, after variable initializers; see [Effective Go - The Init Function](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#init) for explanation.

You can solve this problem by completely removing global variable `Conn` and `init()` function from `models/meme.go` and call `GetDB()` in each model function to obtain connection.